# vb.net MS Word crash cleanup

Tags: vb.net, file, ms-word, code-cleanup

I have a program that takes a template .docx file and populates it with data, saving a copy afterwards. The program itself works fine and I got a nice try..catch in main sub in case something fails, so the file is closed regardless.

The problem is that if it crashes completely, i.e. is forced to close (or manually force closed if it hangs), it will keep the process running with the opened template, so next time it;s launched, you'll get the read only error when trying to open it.

So the question: Is there a way to clean up afterwards, without having to end process via task manager? Or maybe a way of opening it without locking it out? Making a temp copy maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with this:

```
Sub KillUnusedWordProcess()
    Dim oXlProcess As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("Winword")
    For Each oXLP As Process In oXlProcess
        If Len(oXLP.MainWindowTitle) = 0 Then
            oXLP.Kill()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```